# Problems recognizing color for pretrained Inception -v3

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm retraining the last layer of a pre-trained Inception V3 model: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining

My image recognition task is to try to identify the species of mushrooms.

When I look at the prediction results for misclassified images, the model is often assigning a mushroom to a species with a similar shape, but a totally different color. So, it seems like the Inception model is more sensitive to shape and less sensitive to color. Unfortunately, color is a very important feature for this problem.

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: I suggest you post your question in  https://datascience.stackexchange.com